# Dynamic radiobutton value to ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax, radio-button

I have many radiobuttons of the same name called "iva", there are like 8, how do I transfer the value with ajax if you choose a diferent one from the default?

```
<td>IVA > Exento <input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivae" checked="true" /></td>
<td>Peq.Contr.Even.Soc.<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivapces" /></td>
<td>Cons.Final<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivacf" /></td>
<td>Peq.Contr.Event<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivapce" /></td>
<td>Resp.Monotr.<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivarm" /></td>
<td>Monotr.Social<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivams" /></td>
<td>Resp.Inscrip.<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivari" /></td>
<td>Contr.Eventual<input type="radio" name="iva" id="ivace" /></td>
```

js???

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. You should set value="" for all radio button.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input:radio[name="iva"]').change(function(){
                var ivaval = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'test.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: "&test="+ivaval,
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                  }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Accept my answer if you can. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow